# Internet Radio player component for Delphi/C++Builder

Tags: delphi, activex, c++builder, shoutcast, icecast

I'm looking for an Internet Radio player (SHOUTcast/IceCast) component for Delphi/C++Builder. Does such a thing exist? ActiveX component OK too.

Thanks.

Comment: SHOUTcast/IceCast are essentially streaming MP3 over HTTP.  It's like downloading an MP3 file that never ends.  There are some caveats, but if you can find a component that will play a streaming MP3, then you are set.  I second SteveJG's suggestion below.

Answer (score 4):

You might try the audio library at: http://www.un4seen.com/

The "BASS" DLLs work fine with Windows Xp. They are not a delphi component of course. They are free for non-commercial use. The download includes a simple Delphi example Internet radio. There are issues that preclude its use for recording functions on some PCs where the recording function is disabled but it  "plays" Internet Radio at whatever quality you require. "BASS"  works very well with Delphi 2007.

Comment: +1 Using the BASS audio library I wrote a minimalistic command line internet radio player in just a couple of hours.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this http://symmetrica.net/newac/ it's free, comes with full source and it has a demo of a radio player.

Comment: out of business

Answer (score 2):

http://code.blitzaffe.com/pages/delphi/files/streaming_radio_library_58-50 (I didn't use it, so I'm not sure if it 100% functional - if it is then update the answers).
also here you have other links:
http://www.un4seen.com/
http://www.dsplayer.de/dspweb/downloads/?view=downloads&start=5&limit=5&id=&layout=

best regards,

Radu